# Query on alphanumeric field with a numeric condition

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get results for all class that has a class id greater than 300. I have tried multiple ways and still can not figure out

```
select c_id
from class
where c_id > '300';

C_ID
---------------
Seminar
WRIT 101
IDIS 302
WRIT 300
ACCT 201
BULA 151
CMAT 201/303
ECON 200
INSS 209
INSS 225
MATH 111
OPRE 201
OPRE 202
INSS 300
MGMT 301
MGMT 315
OPRE 315
INSS 315
INSS 406
INSS 421
INSS 427
INSS 460
INSS 490

23 rows selected.
```

The desired result will give a total count of courses with course ID above 300 or more (ex: INSS 300, INSS421, MGMT 315 etc should be included in the count)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You'll need to trim off the first 5 characters in order to compare to the course number (assuming the course category code is always 5 digits) and decide how to deal with 201/303. Look at the documentation for your DB about how to trim / exclude characters in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be working in t-SQL (e.g., SQL Server), then try something like:

```
SELECT c_ID
FROM class
WHERE TRY_CAST(RIGHT(c_ID, 3) AS int) > 300
```

If you truly just need the count and not a list, then

```
SELECT COUNT(c_ID) AS ClassCount300Plus
FROM class
WHERE TRY_CAST(RIGHT(c_ID, 3) AS int) > 300
```

should suffice.

Edited:  It looks like you'll have conversion errors if things like "Seminar" are in your list of c_ID's.  So, you should probably work with TRY_CAST instead of CONVERT.

Also note that this won't work for any 4-digit c_IDs if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some assumptions about what you need to handle "CMAT 201/303".  Given the context of this being class lists, I assumed that was two separate classes.  So the query I came up with is fairly long in order to handle that one case.  Furthermore, since you need to use that class number to filter (i.e. classes > 300), this needs to be numeric so *something* needs to be done with that slash.  If this should not be split into two classes, more detail would be needed in the original post.

To make the SUBSTRINGs and WHERE clauses easier to read, I created the CTE "pos".  This is not necessary, but I thought it made it easier to understand.

```
WITH pos AS (
    SELECT C_ID, CHARINDEX(' ', C_ID) AS spaceIndex, CHARINDEX('/', C_ID) AS slashIndex 
    FROM class
)
,SPLIT AS (
    --Get everything without a slash
    SELECT LEFT(C_ID, spaceIndex - 1) AS CLASS, SUBSTRING(C_ID, spaceIndex + 1, LEN(C_ID) - spaceIndex + 1) AS NUM
    FROM pos 
    WHERE spaceIndex > 0
    AND slashIndex = 0
    UNION 
    --Get the left side of the slash
    SELECT LEFT(C_ID, spaceIndex - 1) AS CLASS, SUBSTRING(C_ID, spaceIndex + 1, slashIndex - spaceIndex - 1) AS NUM
    FROM pos
    WHERE spaceIndex > 0
    AND slashIndex > 0
    UNION 
    --Get the right side of the slash
    SELECT LEFT(C_ID, spaceIndex - 1) AS CLASS, SUBSTRING(C_ID, slashIndex + 1, LEN(C_ID) - slashIndex) AS NUM
    FROM pos
    WHERE spaceIndex > 0
    AND slashIndex > 0
)
SELECT * 
FROM SPLIT
WHERE NUM > 300
ORDER BY 1
;
```